# Get Drupal 8 Roles label

Tags: roles, drupal-8

I'm loading a user to get his roles, but I only get the role machine name. I found the way to load those roles:

```php
$roles = Role::loadMultiple($user->getRoles());
```

but now I need to get the labels of those roles.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```php
foreach ($roles as $role) {
  $label = $role->label();
}
```